# SwiftUI - how do customise navigation bar on one screen only?

Tags: swift, xcode, navigationbar, swiftui

At WWDC, one talk gave an example of how the ‘`Reminders`’ app customises the `Navigation Bar` on different screens. They shared how they did this:

```
let appearance = navigationBar.standardAppearance.copy()
navigationItem.standardAppearance = appearance
```

How would the actual implementation work? I’m not quite sure where that code slots in, in order to customise one navigation bar.

Any help would be super appreciated!

Answer (score -2):

In viewWillAppear set this value

`UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "MuseoSans-500", size: 19)!,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black
]`

and on viewWillDisappear reset all the values.

Comment: I’m looking to implement this in SwiftUI, introduced at WWDC :)